# jQuery get where the video is currently at

Tags: jquery, mysql, html, video

So I am making a streaming website and I wanted the user to be able to resume where they were last at, just by doing `AJAX` requests every 10 seconds to send to the DataBase where the user is at, but I wanted to know what the method for getting where the current viewer is actually at?

An example is a `jQuery` function that when applied to a video tag possibly can return what `minute:second` the user is sitting on then set that as a variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your timer loop you would want to call

```
var curTime = $("#videoID").text(currentTime);
```

or

```
var curTime = document.getElementById("videoID").currentTime;
```

which will return the current time in seconds (first uses jQuery, second plain JavaScript) and then save that to your database.

So, something like:

```
setTimeout(savetime, 10000)
....
function savetime() {
    var curTime = document.getElementById("videoID").currentTime;
    // save curTime to a cookie or remote database via ajax call
}
```